# i don't want to pass worked_dates dynamically ,i want to pass worked_dates in between range in pivot

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [TM_UserID],
        [FullName],
        [Worked_dte],
        [Worked_Hours]
    FROM @Reporting_User_Timesheet
    WHERE [worked_dte] BETWEEN '2014-04-04'
            AND '2014-04-06'
    ) AS sourceTable
Pivot(sum([Worked_Hours]) FOR [Worked_dte] IN ([2014-04-04], [2014-04-05], [2014-04-06])) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark, obviously, but here's how I understood your question.

First, you need a calendar table to get the dates for the range:

http://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/

After that, construct the needed PIVOT query and execute it dynamically:

```
declare @range_start date, @range_end date;

select @range_start = '20140404', @range_end = '20140406';

declare @collist nvarchar(max);
SET @collist = stuff((select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar,date,112)) 
            FROM calendar 
            WHERE Datue BETWEEN @range_start AND @range_end
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

declare @q nvarchar(max);
set @q = '
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [TM_UserID],
        [FullName],
        [Worked_dte],
        [Worked_Hours]
    FROM @Reporting_User_Timesheet
    WHERE [worked_dte] BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(varchar, @range_start, 112) + '''
            AND ''' + CONVERT(varchar, @range_end, 112) + '''
) AS sourceTable
Pivot (
    sum([Worked_Hours]) FOR [Worked_dte] IN (' + @collist + ')
) AS PivotTable
';

exec (@q);
```